# support-v4.Fragment vs Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

If I support from SDK 15 should I use `support-v4 Fragment` instead of a `Fragment`?

I´m trying to use `FragmentSupport.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this)` and implement the new M permission model but it needs a Fragment.

ex:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class MyBaseFragment extends Fragment {

    public ... {
        if (FragmentCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this)){  // ERROR, needs Fragment not v4 Fragment
            ....
        }
    }

}
```

FragmentCompat: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.html

Comment: Yes, to achieve backward compatibility you need to use support v4 Fragment. Also, it is a good practice to make your app backward compatible. If you can post a portion of the code that clarifies the error causing line and how you're importing the fragment from the support library, it will be more clear to us, where we may be able to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Dania I edited the question

Comment: what is this `FragmentSupport` class?

Comment: I just edited again, It´s from the support library. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.html

Comment: @danielgomezrico instead of using FragmentSupport try to use Fragment.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this), and let me know what you get.

Comment: @danielgomezrico I think that Fragment is already imported from support v4 library, it supports backward compatibility, no need to use FragmentSupport.

Comment: :O! I will take a look on that.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using layouts like tabs (i.e ViewPager), then support library will be required. In the case with "only" fragments and minSDK 15, they aren't necessary.By the way, it is good to use support libraries because it does not require much more effort and you can change things later if you need. You can read detailed [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) here to find out if it is needed for your project or not.

Comment: why do I need to use support fragment for ViewPager?

Comment: You need it since viewpager comes with support v4 library and it can only host support fragments

Comment: There's viewpager in v13 support library which supports native fragments.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the comment. I didn't aware of it previously

Comment: Would be great to have an answer for this updated for 2016 reality of things. Should we FINALLY switch over to the base Fragment / Activity for Android development? Assuming we realistically only need to support v19 / Android 4.4 and newer (KitKat, Android 4.4)?

Answer (score 1):

`android.support.v4.app.Fragment` should be used everywhere instead of `android.app.Fragment` because the latter one was deprecated in Android 9.

Answer (score 0):

`android.app.Fragment` was introduced in API level 11. If your minSDKVersion < 11 then you must use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` class to support backward compatibility. As you mentioned, your app has API level 15, you must use `android.app.Fragment`.